# PHPMyAdmin issue: Is it advisable to assign a very large value to `$cfg['MaxExactCount']`?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL table with exactly 1 million rows of dummy data for testing purposes. However when I click the table's "browse" option, this is what I get:

[image]

Notice how it says there are only 994,622 records whereas I know there are more.

Funny thing is I can still retrieve those invisible records if I perform a search. For instance, the `PHONE` field is filled with numbers incrementing from 00000000 through 01000000; thus, the row containing the value 00999999 should exist. And it does:

[image]

However, as per the "Browse" screen, the last row in view is the one with the value "00994625." Here's a screenshot that shows the last record; do note the absence of any "next" arrow/link:

[image]

I haven't tried exporting so not sure if all records will export. I managed to fix this problem by adding `$cfg['MaxExactCount']` to my **config.inc.php** file. However, I am concerned if this is advisable. I am anticipating my table to grow indefinitely once live and could eventually wind up with several millions of rows. Would it be alright if I just assigned a very large value, say 10000000000, to `$cfg['MaxExactCount']`? What are the pitfalls and how to avoid them? Also, do shared hosting providers generally allow one the access to alter this particular file?

Comment: If you are anticipating a database of many millions of rows, I would recommend using a more robust MySQL GUI client than PHPMyAdmin, perhaps MySQL Workbench instead. The load incurred by increasing the count is placed on the database server (which may or may not also be the web server, probably is if it's shared hosting). As far as I know though, that setting affects client performance when you are inspecting tables, not in regular querying. http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#the-number-of-rows-for-innodb-tables-is-not-correct

Comment: As to whether a shared host permits modifying the configuration, that probably varies widely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you've correctly diagnosed the problem, at least it seems that way. As you've probably seen in the [documentation](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_MaxExactCount), the MaxExactCount directive is basically used to configure at what point phpMyAdmin uses a faster but inexact row count.

Whether it's a good idea to change it is pretty much up to you. The problem would be performance based and depends on your situation (table structure, server specs and load, etc) but it's worth trying to see what happens.

If you're able to modify `config.inc.php` then go for it; some hosts provide phpMyAdmin by putting a copy of the phpMyAdmin folder in your web root (in which case you'll be able to modify config.inc.php directly), others use one centrally located copy and configure the web server to make it appear under your domain (in which case you probably won't even be able to *find* the phpMyAdmin folder, much less modify it). If they don't give you access, you can easily [install your own](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#quick-install) phpMyAdmin instance to your own web root, giving the folder a different name from what your provider uses so as to not conflict, and make whatever modifications you want.